# Different method parameter using generic from the interface parameter that implements it

Tags: java

I have an interface like this:

```
   public interface IEventListener
   {
       public <T extends MyCustomObject> void onEvent(final T object);

       public <T extends MyCustomObject> void onEventTest2(final T object);
   }
```

and in some other class that implements this interface i want call the same method but define whatever parameter i want like:

```
public class MyClass implements IEventListener
{
   @Override
   public <T> void onEvent(final Player player)
   {
     // My code here
   }

   @Override
   public <T> void onEventTest2(final Item item)
   {
     // My code here
   }
}
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Both of these methods look surprising and reflective of confusion in your design.  Could you give us a little more code?  For example, it's not clear if these generic parameters belong on your methods or on your types.

Comment: Usually when people ask a question like this it turns out what they actually need is a type parameter at the class-level like `interface IEventListener<T>` but it's hard to tell without knowing more about how you're using this.

Comment: It looks like you should have `interface IEventListener<T> { public void onEvent(T object); } class MyClass implements IEventListener<Player> { public void onEvent(Player player) { ... } }`

Comment: I did more edit. I use it using multiple methods and multi objects. I want define each parameter different on it's method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems very clear, now, that your generics should be on the type, not the method -- and with your edit, you'll just need multiple parameters, i.e.

```
interface IEventListener<T1 extends MyCustomObject, T2 extends MyCustomObject> {
   void onEvent(T1 object);

   void onEventTest2(T2 object);
}

public class MyClass implements IEventListener<Player, Item> {
   @Override public void onEvent(Player player) { ... }
   @Override public void onEventTest2(Item item) { ... }
}
```

There is not going to be any way you can have the generics on the methods; they must be on the type.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the only way to do cause if i have like 15 methods i need define 15 parameters next to interface. Thats weird

Comment: If you have 15 methods, it doesn't seem likely that you want to use generics or an interface at all.  Just make `onPlayer`, `onItem`, etc. methods.  Alternately, make separate interfaces and implement all the appropriate ones: `PlayerListener`, `ItemListener`, etc.  There are other approaches to this problem that may be more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: PS. I just wanted to avoid in some classes i implement IEventListener and i know the type is Player to avoid cast it everytime and have it already ready.